# How to get int value of time stamp which includes milliseconds in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, nsdate, nsnumber

```
 NSNumber * uniqueId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970])];
```

Milliseconds is not included in the above code.If i used like below code ,it is printing negative values.

```
NSNumber * uniqueId1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000)];
```

Can we get time stamp with milliseconds as int????

Comment: can you add some ex

Answer (score 1):

@AnjaniG you can use one of them..

```
NSString *strTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
int timestamps = [strTimeStamp intValue];
NSLog(@"number int = %d",timestamps);
```

Comment: or you need still other output then let me know

Comment: I need to store it the value in int and with milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

You should not use an `Int`, `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000` is bigger than `INT_MAX`. You should use `long long` to store the value.

`NSNumber * uniqueId1 = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000)];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are casting a floating point to an integer.

As [per the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1407504-timeintervalsince1970?language=objc), `timeIntervalSince1970` returns an `NSTimeInterval`, [which is a double](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimeinterval), not an integer.

1. In your first code example, you're actually discarding the milliseconds by casting.
2. In your second code example, you are overflowing the integer. After multiplying the value by 1000, it is too large to fit in an integer.

In the end, you're just doing too much code and you shouldn't need to really worry about this.

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [NSDate date].timeIntervalSince1970;
NSNumber *timestamp = @(interval * 1000.);
```

Here, I use the proper documented type of `NSTimeInterval`. Then I multiply that by 1,000 to change seconds to milliseconds. Finally, I use [Clang literal syntax](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#nsnumber-literals) to instruct the compiler to create the appropriate `NSNumber`.